# ical4j - Find Event based on the UID

Tags: java, calendar, ical4j

I´m using ical4j to create my .ical - File and save events.
But how can I find a stored VEvent in the calendar?

I have the following code, but it´s not working?
I got my calendar -> this is working and I debug this already

```
public VEvent findEvent(CalendarExtern calendarExtern, String hashId) throws IOException, ParserException {

    Calendar calendar = readCalenderFromFile(calendarExtern);

    for (Component component : calendar.getComponents(Component.VEVENT)) {
          if (hashId.equals(component.getProperty(Property.UID))) {
              VEvent event = (VEvent) component;
                return event;
          }
        } 

    return null;
}
```

Any ideas? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

component.getProperty(Property.UID) returns a Property so what you really want to do is:

```
if (hashId.equals(component.getProperty(Property.UID).getValue()))...
```

Of course you, depending on your input, you may want to check for components without a UID property before doing getValue().

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Also note that there may be more than one event with the specified UID if you are reading a calendar that supports revisions. In such cases you may want to use a `ComponentGroup` to find the latest revision of a particular event.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach using a [ComponentGroup](http://ical4j.github.io/docs/ical4j/api/3.0.0/net/fortuna/ical4j/model/ComponentGroup.html) to find the latest revision of an event:

```
ComponentGroup<VEvent> group = new ComponentGroup(
         calendar.getComponents(Component.VEVENT),
         new Uid(hashId));

return group.getLatestRevision();
```